# Do not start the activity inside the if-case

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a problem with this part of code

```
Intent myactivity = new Intent(context, MyKeyboard.class);
myactivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                 
context.startActivity(myactivity);
```

if i put it in the "if" there isn' t any response but if i put it outside it works

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {



        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

                if(null == bundle) return;

                String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);


                if( phonenumber=="11111111111" ) {

                    Intent myactivity = new Intent(context, MyKeyboard.class);
                    myactivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(myactivity);


                }      

        }

}
```

Comment: Here is an explanation about [comparing strings in java.](http://www.zparacha.com/java-string-comparison/#.T5mPUKsV3ZI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
phonenumber=="11111111111"
```

replace the above line with below and try

```
phonenumber.equals("11111111111")
```